# How to verify safely if the default browser for ShellExec is IE

Tags: delphi

The code below should detect IE but its giving a wrong output with Crome.

Why this code does not work in Win7 + Chrome;   How can I detect IE is not default one?

```
  if pos('iexplore.exe',lowercase(CheckBrowser(nil))) >0 then say "yes its IEE!!"

function CheckBrowser(Sender: TObject) : ansistring;
 var
   Reg: TRegistry;
   KeyName: string;
   ValueStr: string;
 begin
 result := '';
   Reg := TRegistry.Create;
   try
     Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
     KeyName     := 'htmlfile\shell\open\command';
     if Reg.OpenKey(KeyName, False) then
     begin
       ValueStr := Reg.ReadString('');
       Reg.CloseKey;
       result := ValueStr;
     end
     else

   finally
     Reg.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Why do you want to check whether IE is the default browser? Wouldn't integrating a browser of your own be more effective? There are several packages available which embed the major ones (except the FireFox one, I think that's an abandoned project) like IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Om my PC I've set IExplore as default.

**Default= IExplore**

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command

  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" %1

Change the default browser to chrome

**Default= Chrome**

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command

  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" %1

**\htmlfile\shell\open\command**  or **http\shell\open\command** doesn't work in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

I must create a html-file and then find the executable

```
function GetDefaultBrowser(): String;
var
  TempPath: String;
  FileHandle: THandle;
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  TempPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetTempPath;
  FileHandle := System.SysUtils.FileCreate(TempPath + 'htmpl.htm');
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    FillChar(Buffer, Length(Buffer), #0);
    if FindExecutable('htmpl.htm', PChar(TempPath), Buffer) > 32 then
    begin
      Result := Buffer;
    end;
    System.SysUtils.FileClose(FileHandle);
    System.SysUtils.DeleteFile(TempPath + 'htmpl.htm');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are leaking the file handle that `FileCreate()` returns. You need to call `FileClose()` before then calling `DeleteFile()`. Also, you need to use `Length(Buffer)` instead of `SizeOf(Buffer)`, especially if you are using Delphi 2009+.

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` looks good here. Not sure what you are getting at.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking in the wrong place. The place to check is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
```

Read the following blog for more details:

[How Does Your Browser Know that It’s Not The Default?](https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/)